# CocoaPods can not build a arm file of type(.a) ,ld: library not found for -lPods-BMedicine

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In my project , I used CocoaPods manager my other APIs like JSONKit ASIHttpRequest.

I vim a Podfile like this:

target "BMedicine" do

pod 'JSONKit', '~> 1.5pre'

pod 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8.2'

pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.6'

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'

pod 'REFrostedViewController', '~> 2.4.5'

pod 'libqrencode', '~> 3.4.2'

end

target "BMedicineTests" do

end

then I use: pod -install (or pod update)

now, my project an run at simulator,and I open Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/(MyProject)/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/

in this directory， I can see many files of ".a", also the file "libPods-(MyProject).a",
I think all the other files depend on the file "libPods-(MyProject).a",so my project can run in simulator .( I get info this .a file in shell, info is i386)

But,but,in other directory :Debug-iphoneOS,there is nothing but MyProject.app ,I think it is the reason for Xcode give me a error.

(null): Library not found for -lPods-MyProject.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I solved this problem,first I set podfile the "platform:ios 7.0"（I think this isn't the important reason）

I googled a few minutes, and Clean my Project ,than I founded a warning ,oh,waning is the important but not everyone think this.

the warning is my project is run armv7s and armv7 ,but my pod.a not contain 'armv7',
and I see this when I pod update :

[!] Found multiple values (`armv7`, `armv7s`) for the architectures (`ARCHS`) build setting for the `Pods` target definition. Using the first.

[!] Found multiple values (`armv7`, `armv7s`) for the architectures (`ARCHS`) build setting for the `Pods-BMedicine` target definition. Using the first.

so I think this is the Reason. and I change my project's Architectures for 'armv7' and set Build Active Architecture Only  = YES
Valid Architetures  = armv7

Now, I can run in my phone.

hum, Most headaches are not coding issues, but compile problems

I hope this can help some people like me.

and last, THE WARNING IS IMPORTANT!!!!!!